# CodeIgniter Suddenly Cannot Upload Image and says Cannot Be Null

Tags: codeigniter-3

Greeting everyone and especially to Senior of CodeIgniter Developer.

I have a problem with website that was built from CodeIgniter (I am not the developer *inherited by previous epmployer*). This website cannot working properly, especially when upload the image and shows warning about

> Error Number: 1048 Column 'article_image' cannot be null

I did try with find the problem on the script and database, but nothing change and because no one change the codes & contents. Today, i try again with changing the "Null into yes" (previously is "No"), and tried to upload the article. It is miracle that it is working but the next problem is the image is gone (broken). I search at other and looking people with same problem with me says that i need to upgrade the CodeIgniter. Mine is 3.0.0 while the latest is 3.1.10. I copy paste the content inside /System and /views/error/cli not making better but make it worse, the image at the web page is gone(missing).

This is my Article_model

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Article_model extends CI_Model {
public function get_all()
{
    // $this->db->order_by('article_date', 'desc');
    // $this->db->order_by('article_view', 'desc');
    // $query = $this->db->get_where('article', array('flag !=' => 3));
    // return $query->result_array();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT A.*,B.*, A.id AS id_article FROM article AS A JOIN category B ON A.article_category = B.id WHERE A.flag != 3 ORDER BY article_date DESC, article_view DESC ");
    return $query->result_array();

}

public function check($article_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('article', array('flag !=' => 3, 'id' => $article_id));
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function get_category()
{
    $query = $this->db->order_by('category_name', 'ASC')->get_where('category', array('flag' => 1));
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function get_tag()
{
    $query = $this->db->order_by('tag_name', 'ASC')->get_where('tag', array('flag' => 1));
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function get_selected_tag($article_id)
{
    $query = $this->db
                ->select('tag.id, tag_name')
                ->join('article_tag', 'tag_id = tag.id')
                ->where(array('tag.flag' => 1, 'article_id' => $article_id))
                ->get('tag');

    return $query->result_array();
}

public function insert()
{
    $this->load->helper('upload');
    $this->load->library('image_moo');

    $image = file_upload('article_image', 'upload/article');

    $this->image_moo->load($image['full_path']);
    $this->image_moo->resize(924, 527)->save($image['path'] . '/' . $image['file_name'], TRUE);
    $this->image_moo->resize_crop(100, 69)->save($image['path'] . '/thumb/' . $image['file_name']);
    $this->image_moo->resize_crop(367, 232)->save($image['path'] . '/cover/' . $image['file_name']);

    $insert_data = array(
        'article_author'    => $this->session->admin_id,
        'article_title'     => $this->input->post('article_title'),
        'article_slug'      => url_title($this->input->post('article_title'), '-', TRUE),
        'article_category'  => $this->input->post('article_category'),
        'article_image'     => $image['file_name'],
        'article_content'   => $this->input->post('article_content'),
        'is_popup'          => $this->input->post('is_poup'),
        'article_date'      => $this->input->post('article_date'),
    );

    $this->db->insert('article', $insert_data);
    $article_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    foreach ($this->input->post('article_tag') as $tag)
    {
        // Check apakah tag itu udah ada di database?
        if (is_numeric($tag))
        {
            $tag_id = $tag;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->insert('tag', array('tag_name' => strtolower(trim($tag)), 'tag_slug' => url_title(trim($tag), '-', TRUE)));
            $tag_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        if ( ! $this->db->get_where('article_tag', array('article_id' => $article_id, 'tag_id' => $tag_id))->row_array())
        {
            $this->db->insert('article_tag', array('article_id' => $article_id, 'tag_id' => $tag_id));
        }
    }
}

public function update($id)
{
    $this->load->helper('upload');
    $this->load->library('image_moo');

    $image = file_upload('article_image', 'upload/article');

    $this->image_moo->load($image['full_path']);
    $this->image_moo->resize(924, 527)->save($image['path'] . '/' . $image['file_name'], TRUE);
    $this->image_moo->resize_crop(100, 69)->save($image['path'] . '/thumb/' . $image['file_name']);
    $this->image_moo->resize_crop(367, 232)->save($image['path'] . '/cover/' . $image['file_name']);

    $insert_data = array(
        'article_author'    => $this->session->admin_id,
        'article_title'     => $this->input->post('article_title'),
        'article_slug'      => url_title($this->input->post('article_title'), '-', TRUE),
        'article_category'  => $this->input->post('article_category'),
        'is_popup'          => $this->input->post('is_popup'),
        'article_content'   => $this->input->post('article_content'),
        'article_date'      => $this->input->post('article_date'),
    );

    if ($image)
    {
        $insert_data['article_image'] = $image['file_name'];
    }

    $article_id = $id;

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('article', $insert_data);

    $this->db->where('article_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('article_tag');

    foreach ($this->input->post('article_tag') as $tag)
    {
        // Check apakah tag itu udah ada di database?
        if (is_numeric($tag))
        {
            $tag_id = $tag;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->insert('tag', array('tag_name' => strtolower(trim($tag)), 'tag_slug' => url_title(trim($tag), '-', TRUE)));
            $tag_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        if ( ! $this->db->get_where('article_tag', array('article_id' => $article_id, 'tag_id' => $tag_id))->row_array())
        {
            $this->db->insert('article_tag', array('article_id' => $article_id, 'tag_id' => $tag_id));
        }
    }
}
}
```

What should i do guys? i did backup but it remain same like after upgraded. Thank you. Web Url (http://www.hidupseimbangku.com/)

Comment: ah almost forgot, this is what always mention

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048

Column 'article_image' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `article` (`article_author`, `article_title`, `article_slug`, `article_category`, `article_image`, `article_content`, `is_popup`, `article_date`) VALUES ('1', 'testing', 'testing', '5', NULL, '

test test

', NULL, '2019-04-11')
Filename: models/admin/Article_model.php

Line Number: 69

after i checked it refer to $this->db->insert('article', $insert_data);

Answer (score 0):

First. If you want to upgrade CI Version you must follow Upgrading Guide one by one. There may be break changes and you need to correct them, you can find this guide here:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrading.html

I suggest you rollback upgrade changes and start again doing one by one. It is not hard, it is just time consuming.

The error you're getting is probably related to an error of uploading process. What is `file_upload`?

I also suggest you read [this](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=upload), for properly file upload.